# Cross.Geolocator iOS in Xamarin.Forms - I don't get location

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, geolocation

I have problem **only with iOS project**. Android works just fine. When I call following line:

```
App.Position = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync();
```

Program goes and never returns to its main thread.

I added in my info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>You are about to use location!</string>
```

I have Cross.GeoLocator version 3.0.4. I've tried to update to 4.X, but I had many conflicts in my solution, so I reverted on this version.

Comment: It seems like you forgot to set `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` in info.plist

Answer (score 0):

First of all be sure that you installed the package into iOS.   After that is complete I followed the documentation [Here](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/GettingStarted.html).

You will need to add a second entry into your info.plist for iOS 11.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access location when open and in the background.</string>
```

An example of how i get the current location would be.

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
var currentLat = position.Latitude;
var currentLong = position.Longitude;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add timeout parameter in the method.

```
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3500));
```